# jQuery change id on client, and control can no longer be found on server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0, jquery-selectors

I have a grid view, where user can add a new row. On the adding of row, the id's are changed like this..

```
$('<div class=".grdLoaded">').load("GridRow.htm", function () {
                    // insert the html
$(_InsertionID).after($(this).html());
// now change the default id(s) that were present on GridRow.htm
// to something that represent current value(s)
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblSNO').attr('id', 'SNo_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblQty').attr('id', 'Qty_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblItemName').attr('id', 'ItemName_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblProcess').attr('id', 'Prc_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblRemarks').attr('id', 'Remarks_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblColor').attr('id', 'Color_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
$('#grdEntry').find('#grdEntry_ctl00_lblAmount').attr('id', 'Amount_' + _insCurRowNumber + '');
```

where `insCurRowNumber` is the current row id that is being added, for the first time its 1, second 2 and so on..
The problem is if I try to access any of these control on server, like this

```
((Label)grdEntry.Rows[i].FindControl("ItemName_1").Text;
```

or event if like this

```
Page.FindControl("ItemName_1")
```

I get a `null reference exception`. Seems like the issue is server side can't find these dynamically generated id(s). If that is the cause how do I circumvent this? If its not the cause then what is causing this behavior and again, how do I find these control(s) to access their value(s)?

**EDIT** : In response to Steven Hunt, the request was in post format, and here's the key's collection.

```
    Request.Form.AllKeys    {string[177]}   string[]
    [0] "__EVENTTARGET" string
    [1] "__EVENTARGUMENT"   string
    [2] "__LASTFOCUS"   string
    [3] "__VIEWSTATE"   string
    [4] "__EVENTVALIDATION" string
    [5] "check" string
    [6] "txtDueDate"    string
    [7] "txtTime"   string
    [8] "txtCustomerName"   string
    [9] "grdEntry$ctl01$txtQty" string
    [10]    "grdEntry$ctl01$txtName"    string
    [11]    "grdEntry$ctl01$txtProcess" string
    [12]    "grdEntry$ctl01$txtRate"    string
    [13]    "grdEntry$ctl01$txtRemarks" string
    [14]    "tags"  string
    [15]    "grdEntry$ctl01$txtColor"   string
    [16]    "txtRemarks"    string
    [17]    "drpCheckedBy"  string
    [18]    "btnSaveBooking"    string
    [19]    "txtCurrentDue" string
    [20]    "a" string
    [21]    "txtDiscount"   string
    [22]    "txtDiscount_TextBoxWatermarkExtender_ClientState"  string
    [23]    "txtDiscountAmt"    string
    [24]    "txtSrTax"  string
    [25]    "txtTotal"  string
    [26]    "txtAdvance"    string
    [27]    "txtBalance"    string
    [28]    "txtItemName"   string
    [29]    "txtItemSubQty" string
    [30]    "txtNewItemName"    string
    [31]    "txtItemCode"   string
    [32]    "hdntemp"   string
    [33]    "hdnItemCode"   string
    [34]    "txtProcessCode"    string
    [35]    "txtProcessName"    string
    [36]    "txtCNameSearch"    string
    [37]    "txtAddress"    string
    [38]    "txtPhoneNo"    string
    [39]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl02$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [40]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl03$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [41]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl04$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [42]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl05$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [43]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl06$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [44]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl07$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [45]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl08$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [46]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl09$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [47]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl10$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [48]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl11$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [49]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl12$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [50]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl13$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [51]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl14$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [52]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl15$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [53]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl16$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [54]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl17$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [55]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl18$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [56]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl19$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [57]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl20$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [58]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl21$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [59]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl22$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [60]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl23$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [61]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl24$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [62]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl25$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [63]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl26$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [64]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl27$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [65]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl28$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [66]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl29$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [67]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl30$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [68]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl31$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [69]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl32$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [70]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl33$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [71]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl34$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [72]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl35$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [73]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl36$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [74]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl37$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [75]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl38$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [76]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl39$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [77]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl40$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [78]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl41$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [79]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl42$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [80]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl43$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [81]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl44$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [82]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl45$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [83]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl46$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [84]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl47$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [85]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl48$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [86]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl49$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [87]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl50$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [88]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl51$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [89]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl52$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [90]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl53$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [91]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl54$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [92]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl55$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [93]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl56$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [94]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl57$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [95]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl58$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [96]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl59$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [97]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl60$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [98]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl61$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [99]    "grdCustomerSearch$ctl62$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [100]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl63$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [101]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl64$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [102]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl65$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [103]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl66$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [104]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl67$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [105]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl68$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [106]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl69$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [107]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl70$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [108]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl71$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [109]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl72$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [110]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl73$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [111]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl74$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [112]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl75$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [113]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl76$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [114]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl77$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [115]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl78$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [116]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl79$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [117]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl80$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [118]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl81$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [119]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl82$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [120]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl83$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [121]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl84$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [122]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl85$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [123]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl86$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [124]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl87$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [125]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl88$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [126]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl89$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [127]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl90$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [128]   "grdCustomerSearch$ctl91$lnkBtnCustomerCode"    string
    [129]   "txtExtraProcess1"  string
    [130]   "txtExtraRate1" string
    [131]   "txtExtraProcess2"  string
    [132]   "txtExtraRate2" string
    [133]   "txtWholeRemark"    string
    [134]   "drpTitle"  string
    [135]   "txtCName"  string
    [136]   "txtCAddress"   string
    [137]   "txtMobile" string
    [138]   "drpPriority"   string
    [139]   "txtNewPriority"    string
    [140]   "txtAreaLocaton"    string
    [141]   "txtRemarks1"   string
    [142]   "txtBDate"  string
    [143]   "txtADate"  string
    [144]   "hdnMAC"    string
    [145]   "hdnEditItemId" string
    [146]   "hdnOption" string
    [147]   "hdnCustId" string
    [148]   "hdnUpdate" string
    [149]   "BranchId"  string
    [150]   "hdnItems"  string
    [151]   "hdnDataValues" string
    [152]   "hdnFirstAdd"   string
    [153]   "hdnCustomerNameFocusOut"   string
    [154]   "hdnCurrentValue"   string
    [155]   "hdnCurrentGrossAmt"    string
    [156]   "isInEditMode"  string
    [157]   "hdnDefaultItem"    string
    [158]   "hdnDefaultProcess" string
    [159]   "hdnDefaultItemProcessRate" string
    [160]   "hdnTaxBefore"  string
    [161]   "hdnAllDiscount"    string
    [162]   "hdnAllTax" string
    [163]   "hdnUrgentRateApplied"  string
    [164]   "hdnAllDiscountFocusOut"    string
    [165]   "isNetAmountInDecimal"  string
    [166]   "hdnRecompTax"  string
    [167]   "hdnRecompDiscount" string
    [168]   "hdnCustCode"   string
    [169]   "hdnTaxAmtRecomp"   string
    [170]   "hdnDisAmtRecomp"   string
    [171]   "hdnBalance"    string
    [172]   "hdnTotal"  string
    [173]   "hdnDiscountValue"  string
    [174]   "hdnGrdRowCount"    string
    [175]   "hdnAllGridData"    string
    [176]   "hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts"  string
```

It doesn't contains anything but data of the header of the grid (those values with `grdEntry$ctl01$txtQty`, not the data of the row(s). But nonetheless, I found my way around, stored all variable in a temporary array and passed that to server, job done!
Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the "id" attribute doesn't get sent back to the server on a postback, that's what the "name" attribute is for. Second, you would want to look in the Request.Form (for post) or Request.QueryString (for get) collections for your data since they would not be bound to controls. ASP .net has to be involved in instanciating the controls, they don't magically exist on the postback when you create them in javascript.